# Do we have to build a sheet each time adding/updating a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Does the sheet get cached? Or do we have to call this each time we want to write to our sheets?

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
```

Comment: You've tagged two languages: Python and Java. Which one are you working in? If you just want the answer for the API (and language is not relevant), then untag both of those languages.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if you want to use 2 times of Sheets API, you can use `sheet` in your script.

Comment: does service get cached anywhere?